# Append varchar2 length in Oracle

Tags: oracle, variable-length, varchar2

I have an oracle procedure which appends varchar2:

`var1 varchar2(32767);`

```
if nvl(length(var1),0) + length(var2||var3||var2||chr(10)||var4||chr(10)||chr(10)) < 32767 
then  var1:= var1||var2||var3||var2||chr(10)||var4||chr(10)||chr(10);
end if;
```

While I'm doing debug I can confirm that:

```
lengh(var1||var2||var3||var2||chr(10)||var4||chr(10)||chr(10))
```

is lower than 32767. But, when I try to execute line 3, it gives me an error:

`"numeric or value error: character string buffer too small"`

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2):

What is your character set?

`LENGTH` function returns count of **characters**, not bytes. If you want to check the length of a string in *bytes*, use the `LENGTHB` function.

The problem here may be the fact that you store characters that take up more than 1 byte. The 32767 is the *bytes* limit for a `VARCHAR2` (`NVARCHAR2` too) string, not characters. So, after concatenation, your string may have less characters than 32767, but it may use more bytes to represent all of them, and you get the `buffer too small` error.

Read more:

- [Oracle's Documentation - LENGTH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm)
- [PSOUG - LENGTH](http://psoug.org/definition/LENGTH.htm)